# Can't set selected item in radiobuttonlist control programmatically

Tags: vb.net

I have 2 arrays of  questions and answers.questions and answers line up in their respective arrays.I am trying to set radio button list with following code.But I am unable to set.The SelectedIndex always returning value of negative one (-1).

```
For i As Integer = 0 To Questions.Length - 1
            CurQuestion = Questions(i)
            CurAnswer = Answers(i)
            Dim rbl As RadioButtonList = DirectCast(plcHolderForm.FindControl("Question_" & CurQuestion), RadioButtonList)
            rbl.SelectedIndex = rbl.Items.IndexOf(rbl.Items.FindByValue("CurAnswer".ToString))
        Next
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're searching for the item with the string of "CurAnswer" as the value, and not the contents of the CurAnswer variable.  Try this:

```
rbl.SelectedIndex = rbl.Items.IndexOf(rbl.Items.FindByValue(CurAnswer.ToString))
```

If that doesn't work, if you set the SelectedValue it should change the selected item. Try this in your last line in the loop:

```
rbl.SelectedValue = rbl.Items.FindByValue(CurAnswer).ToString
```